# Detect if a set pixels crossing the boundary of the bounding box

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to to do litterbug detection on a highway, and for that I want to detect the cars first, and then If a set of pixels were detected crossing the boundary of the bounding box, it should be marked as litter. But I don't know how to detect this when an object (A set of pixels) crossing the bounding box in OpenCV.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('CarsDrivingUnderBridge.mp4')
fgbg =  cv2.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()

while True:
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)

    if not ret:
        break 
    frame_r = cv2.resize(frame, (640, 480))
    fgmask_r = cv2.resize(fgmask, (640, 480))


    contours,h = cv2.findContours(fgmask_r, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL , cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    # contours,h = cv2.findContours(fgmask_r, cv2.RETR_TREE , cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    for cnt in contours:
        area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        # print (area)
        if area <100:
            continue
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        offset = 3    
        cv2.rectangle(frame_r,(x-offset,y-offset),(x+w+offset,y+h+offset),(0,255,0),2)


    cv2.imshow('Origional', frame_r)
    cv2.imshow('fg', fgmask_r)


    if cv2.waitKey(75) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: image description]

Answer (score 1):

Follow this steps:

- Draw in white a bounding box over a black image.
- Do a "bitwise and" betwen the bounding box image and the image of the object (A): `overlap = cv.bitwise_and(bbox, A)`.
- Count the number of pixel that overlaps: `cv.countNonZero(overlap)`. If there are any it's detected.

Comment: I draw a white bounding box on each car on the black and white image , how do i get only the bounding box to **bitwise_and** with the ROI. bbox is the return image not only the bounding box. **bbox=cv2.rectangle(fgmask_r, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 255, 255), 1)**

Comment: Sorry I'm not understanding your question. You can these steps with all the bounding boxes or one by one, depends on if you want to detect the exact bounding box it's crossing or any of all. Solves that yout question?